# I am. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am.
>   I am a king with a castle but seldom a crown.
>   I am able, with but a single step, to assemble the peoples unto me.
>   I am, with a change of heart, beginning to be softer.
>
> Give me an endless jet and make me soar.
>   Even when I have a rough start, I'll go the distance and then some.
>
> A new beginning lets me make alternate choices;
>     but if I then go left instead of right, I'll agitate myself into a frenzy.
>   Replace part of me and I'll at last relax, a worshipper of the sun.
>
> Deus dedit nobis hodie.  Carpe diem!

**Who am I?**
**What seven things can I become?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> a FATHER.

I am a king with a castle but seldom a crown.

> Perhaps because "an Englishman's home is his castle".

I am able, with but a single step, to assemble the peoples unto me.

> That is, to GATHER them. (F to G is not only a single-letter change, but moves only one step along the alphabet.)

I am, with a change of heart, beginning to be softer.

> ...and FATTER. (As I failed to notice and Rubio pointed out to me in TSL, the right way to parse this is "with a change of (heart beginning)": i.e., the H changes.)

Give me an endless jet and make me soar.

> Insert E (from jEt) making FEATHER, though personally I wouldn't exactly say that a feather soars.

Even when I have a rough start, I'll go the distance and then some.

> You will, in other words, go FARTHER. ("R" is the start of "rough", of course.)

A new beginning lets me make alternate choices;

> Which would you RATHER?

but if I then go left instead of right, I'll agitate myself into a frenzy.

> No need to work yourself up into a LATHER about it.

Replace part of me and I'll at last relax, a worshipper of the sun.

> You will, in other words, be a sun-BATHER.

Deus dedit nobis hodie. Carpe diem!

> Well, today is FATHER'S DAY...

Comment: Entirely correct - well done. I couldn't find a better clue than soar, but I figured if someone got the rest they'd get that from context :)

Comment: Thanks. I've accordingly removed some of the perhapses. Nice puzzle.

Comment: Endless jet = "E", not "JE"?

Comment: Yup. It's lost *both* ends.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot here, but why not:

> The Sun?

*I am a king with a castle but seldom a crown.*

> Not sure what the castle is here, but the solar corona can only be seen during a total eclipse.

*I am able, with but a single step, to assemble the peoples unto me.*

> Unto? Well, I dunno, but when the sun rises, the peoples wake up and gather outside.

*I am, with a change of heart, beginning to be softer.*

> Related to the Solar Core?

*Give me an endless jet and make me soar.

Even when I have a rough start, I'll go the distance and then some.*

> Related to the speed of light? Photons have a rough start in the core of the Sun, taking a long time to reach the surface, but then they shoot out at the speed of light (endless jet?), never slowing down until it hits something.

*A new beginning lets me make alternate choices;

  but if I then go left instead of right, I'll agitate myself into a frenzy.

Replace part of me and I'll at last relax, a worshipper of the sun.*

> Not sure about this one, but the Sun is mentioned...

*Deus dedit nobis hodie. Carpe diem!*

> The day.

*Who am I?*

> The Sun

*What seven things can I become?*

> The seven colors of the rainbow: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo and violet.

Comment: Note the [tag:wordplay] tag ... (Also, hello! :-) Didn't know you were on Puzzling too.)

Comment: What about a son? He can become father, grandfather, nephew, uncle, cousin and grandson. Also, Shakespeare's *I'm too much in the sun [or son]* is an allusion to hamlet, which you could probably work into the king part, and you have the sun option + the wordplay @Randal'Thor mentioned. Although *replace a part of me* is probably talking about letters.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh right, I forgot the wordplay tag... I originally had an answer that used wordplay involving playing cards and Dark Souls, but ended up with this answer but lost the wordplay along the way. It's basically my first answer, so I wouldn't say I "am on Puzzling" yet, hehe.

Comment: As @Randal'Thor points out, [tag:wordplay] is in play here, which your answer doesn't use. I am pretty sure when the right answer is found there will be no question it is the right answer. Having said all this, one of your answers contains one of the seven ....