# I am ... not a political riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> I am.
>   With the left wing, I seek to ban suffragettes.
>   With the same right wing, I'm for a third party.
>   Remove that wing from me, and I'll be leaving.
>   Make one of me Dutch, and I'll join the army.

**Who or what am I?**

Comment: Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52728/5373).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I am.

> I **exist**.

With the left wing, I seek to ban suffragettes.

> A **sexist** might be opposed to women's right to vote.

With the same right wing, I'm for a third party.

> **Exists** is the third-person ("third party") form of **exist**.

Remove that wing from me, and I'll be leaving.

> Remove the **s** from **exist** to get **exit**.

Make one of me Dutch, and I'll join the army.

> Replace the **x** with **nl** (for *Nederlands*, Dutch) to get **enlist**.

I am … not a political riddle

> No, despite all the talk about left wing, right wing and parties you are not.

Comment: Nice. I was far down a political path in trying to solve this non-political one; Robert Borden was a prime minister in Canada, who was a member of the Liberal (left wing), Conservative (right wing) and Unionist (third party) in his life, tried to ban suffragettes from the country in 1912 – and the Canadian flag has a leaf in it, which is almost "leaving"…

Comment: I don't understand how s corresponds to left wing. Maybe the language barrier?

Comment: @Narusan: Wing is used figuratively for an added letter at the beginning (left) or at the end (right). That this letter is an s isn't stated in the riddle, but it is clear that the same letter must be added to the front, added to the rear and removed from the original word.

Comment: Excellent! I was sure the last line had to be ENLIST more or less from first reading, but the rest escaped me entirely.

Comment: Nicely done, Mr Oehm!